# Как узнать количество прикреплённых файлов на go?

Tags: post, golang, fileupload, upload

Я отправляю форму на сервер, к которой прикрепляю файлы картинок.
Изначально количество картинок не известно.
Форма имеет такой вид

```
<input type="file" name="file_1">
```

Если пользователь добавил несколько фотографий, то будет

```
<input type="file" name="file_1">  
<input type="file" name="file_2">
```

Я беру данные из одного файла так `file, _, err := r.FormFile("file_1")`
Как в go узнать количество файлов и перебрать каждый из них?

Comment: Скорее всего в документации к библиотеке это написано. Какой библиотекой вы пользуетесь чтобы разбирать запрос?

Answer (score 1):

```go
func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //парсим мультипарт форму
    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(200000)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
        return
    }
    //получаем формконтейнер с указателями на распарсенные формы
    //доступно только после вызова `ParseMultipartForm` 
    formdata := r.MultipartForm
    //и получаем список указателей на файловые дескрипторы именованной формы со списком файлов
    //по сути это список открытых дескрипторов, так что обычный len(files) покажет общее количество файлов
    files := formdata.File["multiplefiles"]
    fmt.Printf("Total files: %v\n", files)
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.